# Fast switch on a slow / older router possible?

Tags: networking, router, routing, network-shares, switch

I wanted to know if this will work as intended - being that I will get full 10G link between computers on the network.

I have a router with 4 x 1G LAN ports, but I will have 10G SFP+ switches all around. Given the switches are unmanaged L2, and router will act as the L3 switch, will I be able to get the benefits of the 10G file transfers given the topology below between Computer A and Computer B?
(All connections are at 10G SFP+, except Router to SW2 is 1G CAT5E)

[image]

Comment: Will the clients be connected to the 10G SFP+ ports?  If they are those clients will communicate between one another at the higher speed, if they are connected to any other ports, then they will be limited to the lower speed, your network diagram does not make that particular fact clear. In fact the diagram does not even show a second client.

Comment: @Ramhound there's non SFP+ 10G too. Most of my network's  built around native copper 10gig gear :D

Comment: are both systems in the same VLAN? if so, and absent any other activity, you should get full 10G bandwidth along that path. that said, its unlikely that a file transfer will ever come close to that speed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - I am aware there are 10G copper ports.  The author just didn't mention their hardware has them.

Comment: @user241252 -  Switch 2 will be limited to 1G, which means any clients connected to SW2, will also be limited to 1G to the rest of the network. It's also not clear what the purpose of SW4 is....

Comment: Switch 2 would be 1g *between* it and the router. If you're connecting inside the same subnet not all clients would be restricted to gigabit. Heck my 10g switches invariably have a mix of 10g and other lesser speeds on the same chassis.

Answer (score 1):

Your router is going to only really come into play for assigning IPs, and when traffic leaves your subnet. Within the same subnet, traffic is going to go from switch to switch *as needed* and not the router. *If* every switch between the two computers is 10G or better you will be running at 10 gig even if your default gateway (the proper term here) is slower.

*Practically* speaking, with overheads, data storage speed limitations and such you're unlikely to hit full 10G with non-network bottlenecks. the 10G is shared amongst other clients too (so we're looking at  'up to 10G between 2 switches'), and Its unlikely you'd be only running 2 clients total with 2 switches. Your router *not* being 10g capable won't be your bottleneck however.